# The server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) [Strapi]

Tags: jwt, nuxt.js, strapi

I am trying to build an app with Nuxt.js (not modified at all) connect it to a Strapi api and I am completely new to this. I followed the tutorial on the Strapi blog to deploy the Strapi api to Heroku and the Nuxt.js app runs locally. Both instances run fine on their own.

But now I when I try a get request (see below) I get the 401 (Unauthorized) response.

```
axios.get(
    'url',
    {headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ${token}'}
    }
)
```

I tried creating different users and changing permissions. But I always get:

> "statusCode": 401,
>       "error": "Unauthorized",
>       "message": "Invalid token."

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I thought the password in the Strapi user panel is the JWT. Am I mistaken? I tried searching the documentation, stackoverflow, ...but couldn't solve my problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you check the header of the request about the token?

Comment: I did just now, because I didn't know before what that was. I don't see anything wrong though. The token I have in the code is there and the host is correct. I don't know what else could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

[Based on the documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/users-permissions.html#login), you need to login (POST /auth/local) to retrieve the JWT and use it in the `Authorization` header for requesting a resource.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the POST was a requirement. I will try that!

Comment: After lots of trying (different authentication methods with postman, local and on heroku, updated strapi, created new api, new users, different permissions..) I still haven't succeeded.

Post to http://localhost:1337/auth/local/register gets me 
"statusCode": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "Please provide your password."

Post to http://localhost:1337/auth/local with Basic Authentication returns
"statusCode": 401,
"error": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Invalid token."

I am probably lacking an understanding of the whole process. Is there any other way to obtain the JWT?

Comment: Are you sure the route is open? Go to the dashboard > Users & Permissions > Roles > Public and make sure the Auth.callback action is checked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **identifier**,
not *username or email*

https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/guides/auth-request.html#setup

```js
const { data } = await axios.post('http://localhost:1337/auth/local', {
  identifier: 'reader@strapi.io',
  password: 'strapi',
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question was some time ago and I don't have the project anymore so I can't say for sure if your answer solves the issue. But yes, now you need to use identifier not username or email.